# Playing Casio LK-100 in Auto-Play Mode without Rhythm & Accompaniment

Tags: rhythm, keyboard

Is it possible to set up a Casio LK-100 so it plays tunes automatically WITHOUT the rhythm, metronome, and accompaniments - only the musical notes?

The user manual seems to be silent on this topic, and it's not very obvious from the console controls how this is done - and if it is even possible.